# How to set a Javascript Symbol as an Object Key?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, javascript-objects

I have a unique case where I need to use a Javacript symbol as an object's key. This is necessary because in order to conform to Sequelize's documentation, there are instances where we need to have something that looks like this:

```
const where = {
    cost: {
        [Op.gt]: 1000,
        [Op.lt]: 2000
    }
}
```

Both `[Op.gt]` and `[Op.lt]` are Javascript symbols that assist with querying. The block of code will query where a property called `cost` is greater than `1000` but less than `2000`. But when I try to programmatically set the key/value pairs like:

`where['cost'][[Op.gt]] = 1000;`

I receive the following error:

> Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

This is a dynamic object, so I cannot hard code the symbols into the `where` query since the next user may not need to query by these parameters. How do I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: `where['cost'][[Op.gt]]` shouldn't that be `where['cost'][Op.gt]`?

Comment: yeah I think @VLAZ is right. you shouldn't have the extra [] when accessing it. you only need to wrap the symbol keys in [] when initializing the object inline.

Comment: it is trying to convert the array to a string, because is is neither a symbol nor a string.

Comment: Hi everyone, I guess I'm just confused because in the sequelize documentation the key's do have brackets around them? What am I missing. Reference here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#where @VLAZ

Comment: You only need the brackets for the object initialisation like you have in your first piece of code. This is when creating [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). When [*accessing* the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) you don't need an extra set of brackets - `obj[property]` is enough. An extra pair of `[]` brackets means something different - it will create an array and then try to make it into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove 1 bracket around your symbol and you will be fine:

```
where['cost'][Op.gt] = 1000;
```

`obj[Op.gt]` means you're accessing an object property with the `Op.gt` name. `obj[[Op.gt]]` means you're accessing an object property with the name equal to an array `[Op.gt]` stringified. Which is similar to below:

```
const arr = [Op.gt];
const propertyName = arr.toString(); // => throw error "Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string"
where['cost'][propertyName];
```